# Как вынести комментарии worpdpress на отдельный поддомен?

Tags: wordpress, поддомены

Есть сайт на **wordpress** `example.com`.
Как можно вынести комментарии с него на отдельный поддомен `comment.example.com` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Можно используя REST API https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/comments/
2. Если сайты example.com и comment.example.com в одной сети мультисайта

```
$original_blog_id = get_current_blog_id(); //comment.example.com

$new_blog_id  = 1; // example.com

switch_to_blog( $new_blog_id ); 

/*
 Получаете необходимые комментарии с example.com
*/

if( $comments = get_comments( $args = [] ) ){
    foreach( $comments as $comment ){
        // действия
    }
}

// переключаете на оригинальный сайт
switch_to_blog( $original_blog_id );
```